# Literature review help, 3D reconstruction of human organs (non-bio nature) using CAD and 3D printers

Tags: thesis, literature-review

My dissertation is on 3D reconstruction of a human kidney (non-biological nature) using CAD software and 3D printers. The main objectives set in brief are:

-know how 3d printers work and identify different 3d printing technologies
-learn how to use CAD software to design or segment human organs then print out using 3D printers.

Now I've never actually done a literature review before and am struggling to see how to structure it so can achieve 1st objective but still write it in a lit review format. Thought about writing about history, current and developing tech, future developments. then going to try to print healthy kidney and unhealthy kidney for comparison. lots of benefits to both clinicians and patients. I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: I don't think this site can help you with a question so narrowly focused on your own research topic.  This is a question that you should discuss with your advisor.  A good start, however, is to read a large number of other papers on similar topics, and see how their literature reviews are structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, even though you have declared that:

> Now I've never actually done a literature review before

But you must review the literature, in a coherent manner, for a couple of reasons. First of all, definition of a graduate thesis is based on the progression of a subject, had which been considerably taken into account by the other researchers, formerly. The literature review lets you depict the former struggles to address your own augmented solution for the problem. By means of such information, you can, efficiently, assert the drawbacks of those strategies and explain the properties of your solution, is which supposed to cover the aforementioned deficiencies. Furthermore, complete literature provides the interested reader a more omni-aspect overview, corresponding to the research subject. It would be very important for the people, are who eager to continue your work and the complete literature will culminate their mind set to acquire novel inceptions from your report for their research path.

I suggest you to consider the history of the previous research in a chronlogical order. That would help the reader to keep the track of the traspositions, implicitly.

Obviously, ***introduction*** section might not be a right place for `future developments`. You better contend those stuffs within the last section of the thesis before references, i.e. ***Conclusion***, ***Concluding Remarks and Future Works*** or so on; because, after the conclusion, you would have enough chance to convince the careful reader that the gap between your contribution and the future-driven anticipations is, deservedly, filled out and they would be the proceeding reasonable paces for the rest of the research in this field.

Literature review's role could be summarized as: "*Tell me what has been done, up to know, and clear about your own contribution corresponding to it*". Therefore, investigating on the details, such as `try to print healthy kidney and unhealthy kidney for comparison` or `ots of benefits to both clinicians and patients` should be accounted within the main body of the thesis.